# Removing Master Hard Drive Password

Tags: hard-drive, passwords

I bought a second hand IBM T42 and discovered that it has a USER+ MASter Hard drive password. 
I know the USER PASSWORD so I can log-in. However I will like to alter the MASTEr password and I am wondering if a complete reformatting of the Hard disk will help me do it.

Any other suggestion to get rid of the Master Password (when it is not known) is welcome too**!

I couldn't find a definitive answer online and any explanation is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**I am not interested in Data Recovery at this point.

Comment: Reformatting should do it unless the password is set via BIOS.

Comment: @RsyaStudios The problem is that bios wouldn't offer any reformatting options. I am wondering if there are reformatting windows tools that can be of some help...

Answer (score 1):

According to the second post in http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=77879 - there's no way to recover from a forgotten Master HDP.

Comment: You could've also referenced the [TP hardware maintenance manual](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/docs/MIGR-46464) itself...

Comment: @vautee I am aware of that post but it was way back in 2005 and I am wondering if there are more recent solutions...

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record:

It is possible to completely reformat the hard-drive and a fresh installation of an OS is possible without the Master HDP.